# Парсер для facebook. Какую схему выбрать

Tags: php, парсер, facebook, facebook-api

Есть задача, нужен парсер постов facebook по фильтру на php. Есть два предпологаемых варианта решения задачи:

1. Сделать все через API graph. Но, как я понял токен дается на 60 дней максимум (без гарантии), значит код придется поддерживать регулярно. Что не желательно
2. Сделать все через c URL и парсить напрямую код страницы, что никогда не делал.

Что выбрать?

Comment: если есть апи, то нужны ООООЧЕНЬ веские аргументы, чтобы его не использовать. Парсить страницу - тот еще адок, особенно если контент динамически через js подгружается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь сложно что-то посоветовать. При использовании Graph API выдается ключ доступа на приложение, а токен генерируется под каждого пользователя (который предоставил права на просмотр своей ленты). Вы планируете парсить пользователей которые подтвердили права вашего приложения или всех подряд? Если второй случай, то здесь только прямой парсинг или Private API.

Парсить страницу напрямую на порядок сложнее, особенно если идет речь о больших объемах данных. Этот вариант очень капризный, требуется тонкая настройка User Agent, заход на страницу с "правильных" IP, а также соблюдение частоты запросов.

В этом случае работы по поддержке кода будет даже больше. К тому же, в случае каких-либо изменений Facebook не будет вас уведомлять об этом.

Можете рассмотреть вариант с Private API, штука тоже капризная, но данные выдает более структурированно.